# In my range slider the track is coming over on thumb while working fine on Chrome

Tags: html, css, mozilla, firefox-developer-tools, rangeslider

Here are my css html that I am using in my website. View attached images for a better understanding of my problem. Tried z-index and other things but not working. Its working fine on chrome and safari but overlapping in mozilla firefox browser.

[Chrome View Image (which is working fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNZ8i.png)

[Mozilla firefox view Image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xISyr.png)

```
    input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #9cc9f8;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #9cc9f8;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 2px solid #3195ff;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* Firefox uses 'moz' prefix instead of 'webkit' */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #9cc9f8;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: 2px solid #3195ff;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
    outline: none; 
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #9cc9f8bb;
}

 <div class="slider">
                    <div style="font-weight: bolder; color: rgb(44, 44, 44); margin-bottom: 14px;">Price</div>
                    <div id="price_slider" class="range-slider">
                        <input value="{{min_price}}" id="min_price_slider" min="50" max="4000" step="500"
                            type="range">
                        <input value="{{max_price}}" id="max_price_slider" min="0" max="8000" step="500"
                            type="range">
                        <span class="rangeValuesPrice"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider">
                    <div style="font-weight: bolder; color: rgb(44, 44, 44); margin-bottom: 14px;">Duration</div>
                    <div id="duration_slider" class="duration-slider">
                        <input value="{{min_duration}}" id="min_duration_slider" min="1" max="60" step="1"
                            type="range">
                        <input value="{{max_duration}}" id="max_duration_slider" min="1" max="60" step="1"
                            type="range">
                        <span class="rangeValuesDuration"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```